# How to pipe into find?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

```bsh
echo <Search> | find / -name <Search>
```

I am trying to achieve something like this.
To get the same result, I am storing my search on a variable and then using find on it but obviously I am not satisfied with it. It would be awesome if I could pipe that right into find.

Comment: why do you prefer the pipe over `SEARCH='*.txt' find / -name $SEARCH`

Comment: It would be convenient to keep the pipe going. :D

Comment: Show us what you have. Don't describe it.

Comment: It would be an overkill to show my whole script thus I narrowed it down to the problem itself. Besides, the question is pretty simple by any standard.

Comment: You should provide a bit more of the left side of the pipe. You simplified it so much, it is not really useful.

Comment: steeldriver would beg to differ. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `xargs` ex.

```
echo "*.c" | xargs -I% find / -name "%"
```

Comment: There you go!
Thanks man!
The irony is I was already using xargs on my script! lol.
It was right under my nose.
BTW, the super user vibe was duly noted from "*.c". XD

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute like this:

```
$ SEARCH='*mp4'
$ find / -name "$(echo $SEARCH)"
```

This will pipe the output of the command into a variable and do things like this:

```
$ find / -name "$(grep XYZ | cut -f2)"
```

You can see more about [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Comment: From what I understood, this is what OP is doing now but they are *not satisfied with it*.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `echo`.

Comment: I understood the OP is doing `SEARCH='*.txt' find / -name $SEARCH`. The `echo` is there only to let him know it is a 'pipe-ish' solution that he can substitute with other commands.

Comment: Both of these will work. I like the 2nd better. However both will stall the pipe. `find` can not start until `cut` ends. It is good if the grep ... cut is quick, and produces little output.